# jQuery - file upload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Up front, the question I have is about the purpose of:

- `data-provides="fileinput"`
- `data-trigger="fileinput"`
- `data-dismiss="fileinput"`

Does `fileinput` need to be unique? I want to have 3 or 4 different photo uploads on one page, so should all of these be different, like `fileinput1`, `fileinput2`, etc?

And what does data-provides/trigger/dismiss all mean? How do they work?

For some more context: I am using Jasny bootstrap for image uploading; see http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput

Using their example, I have used this code:

```
<div class="s-item fileinput fileinput-new s-photo" data-provides="fileinput">
    <div class="s-photo-explain">Upload a photo</div>
    <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
            <span class="fileinput-new">New photo</span>
            <span class="fileinput-exists">Change photo</span>
            <input class="s-input" type="file" name="s-photo">
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove photo</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried? Their example page has multiple instances.

Comment: Yep, I tried it with multiple images - I thought using .fileinput('clear') meant I'd need to do it to each one but it turns out it's done on the class level. All good now!